# Redux Saga watcher not getting dispatched action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to setup Redux-Saga in my create-react-app project. I'm following a tutorial but somehow the dispatched action is not triggering Redux-Saga watcher. It is a login functionality without integrating the API first (just wanted to wrap my head around how Redux-Saga works).

Here's a snippet of my login action

```
export const userLogin = (username) => ({
    type: USER_LOGIN,
    payload: {username},
});
```

Heres a copy of my loginSaga

```
import { take } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { USER_LOGIN } from '../utils/constants';


function* handleUserLogin(action){
    console.log('action: ', action);
}

export default function* watchUserLogin(){
    yield take(USER_LOGIN, handleUserLogin);
}
```

Here's my rootSaga

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import loginSaga from '../components/Login/saga/loginSaga';

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([loginSaga()]);
}
```

And here's how I'm applying it to the store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootSaga from '../sagas';

import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const configureStore = () => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ?
            compose(
                applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
                window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
            ) : applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    );
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

I'm not getting the console log on handleUserLogin(). Let me know if there is something I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I believe `createStore` needs `initialState` passed as the second argument followed by the enhancer for three arguments in total. That could be the issue if the sagaMiddleware is then not being hooked up to the store.

Comment: No it doesn't. Initial state can be provided in reducer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your saga in `while(true)` to get it running. Otherwise it only waits for the first action and then ends the generator. Also you can use `takeEvery` or `takeLatest` instead.

```
export default function* watchUserLogin() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(USER_LOGIN, handleUserLogin);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @Clarity , could you please look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732330/saga-watcher-function-not-being-called-after-re-login?noredirect=1#comment133598245_75732330

thanks

Answer (score 1):

how about 'takeEvery'?

```
import { takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';

export default function* watchUserLogin() {

    yield takeEvery(USER_LOGIN, handleUserLogin);

}
```